# How to select elements in javascript by class name matching with multiple class names ?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to write a javascript which will select an element, which matches with either of the values"_3eAQiD" or "_2UDlNd"? The page I am using keeps on changing the class name frequently?

Presently, I am using the following code :

```
result.item =  getItemName("_2UDlNd");
```

I pass the class name "_2UDlNd" to a getItemName() function, where I use it as an argument to get the element by class name :

```
itemName = document.getElementsByClassName(item_class)[0].innerText;
```

However, is there any way, I can pass multiple classnames, separated by OR or in teh form of an array, to the getItemName() function, so that 'getElementsByClassName' can select the item with any of the class names which matches with the class name?

Something like this :

```
result.item =  getItemName("_2UDlNd" || _3eAQiD);
```

My problem is since the webpage keeps on changing the class name, I have to continously update the classname in the getItemName function? Any way by which I cna make the process dynamic?

Comment: I'm confused, `_3eAQiD` is some kind of input whose value is the className you want?  What does your getItemName function do?

Comment: I'm confused too, please post your getItemName function.

Comment: Yes, _3eAQiD is one of the class name.                                                result.item =  getItemName("_3eAQiD");                                                                               function getItemName( item_class){
  itemName = document.querySelectorAll(item_class)[0].innerText; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
result.item = document.querySelectorAll("._2UDlNd,._3eAQiD")[0].innerText;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried  the follwoing :                                                  
        result.item =  getItemName("._3eAQiD , ._2UDlNd");                                 and the in getItemName function I passed :function getItemName( item_class){
  itemName = document.querySelectorAll(item_class)[0].innerText;   This is working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` and commas:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('._3eAQiD , ._2UDlNd'));
```

```html
<div class="_3eAQiD">
  A
</div>
<div class="_2UDlNd">
  B
</div>
```